# Expo/React-Native/React-redux - Reducer doesn't update store

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

Hello Stackoverflow first time posting please guide if done incorrectly,
I'm currently working on a weatherApplication for to practice but I'm having an issue updating a new attribute I've added to my store "focusedIndex".

The way it works is I click on city from an array I've stored in the store. Index is used to attain the data in array but I want to store that index as I want to use it to get its lat, lon later on in googleMap component.

1) In CityFocusContainer.js I trigger the action.

2) The reducer does trigger the correct method and displays the appropriate data. (Simple Number - I also double checked with typeof)

3) Assign the new value that was passed to the state

4) The reducer exits and the rest of the app continues and final state of the store is returned, the focusIndex stays the same as the initial state (1) never changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Please let me know if there are any questions

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
isLoading                                  : false, 
currentLocation                            : {},
localWeather                               : {},
weatherList                                : [],
listCounter                                : 1,
focusedCity                                : [],
focusListCounter                           : 1,
focusedCurrent                             : {},
focusIndex                                 : 1 }; 

case 'FOCUS_INDEX'                     :
        console.log("This is Focus Index " + action.fIndex)

return {
            ...state,
            focusIndex    : action.fIndex,
        }
```

CityFocusContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getWeatherAsync, getAdditionalWeatherAsync } from '../utils/weatherFuncs'
import CityWeather from '../components/CityWeather'
import WeatherForDays from '../components/WeatherForDays'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import GoogleMap from '../components/googleMap';

class CityWeatherContainer extends Component {

async componentDidMount () {

    this.props.setLoading()
    const { navigation } = this.props
    const cityIndex = navigation.getParam('cityListIndex', 'NO-ID') 
    const focusedCity = this.props.cityList[cityIndex - 1]
    this.props.setIndex({ CI : navigation.getParam('cityListIndex', 'NO-ID')});
    const highNoon = "12:00:00"

<--- some more code here ---> 

this.props.loading ? <Text>loading....</Text> : <GoogleMap />

<--- some more code here ---> 

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    cityList         : state.weatherList,
    f_cityList       : state.focusedCity,
    loading          : state.isLoading
}
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    setLoading       : ()               => dispatch ({type : 'SET_LOADING'}),
    storeCityInFocus : (cityI)          => dispatch ({type : 'FOCUSED_CITY', cityinfo : cityI }),
    storeFocusC      : (focusedCurrent) => dispatch ({type : 'FOCUSED_CURRENT', cFocused : focusedCurrent}),
    resetData        : ()               => dispatch ({type : 'CLEAR_CITY_DATA'}),
    setIndex         : (indexToBeSent)  => dispatch ({type : 'FOCUS_INDEX', fIndex : indexToBeSent}),
}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CityWeatherContainer)
```

googleMap.js

```
class GoogleMap extends Component {

componentDidMount () {
    console.log("This is the index " + this.props.cIndex)
}

<--- some more code here ---> 

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    cityList         : state.weatherList,
    cIndex           : state.focusIndex
}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GoogleMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'FOCUS_INDEX'                     :
        console.log("This is Focus Index " + action.fIndex.CI)

return {
            ...state,
            focusIndex    : action.fIndex,
        }
```

You have the value defined as focusIndex everywhere, but you have it called out as focusedIndex in the component mapping:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    cityList         : state.weatherList,
    cIndex           : state.focusedIndex
}
}
```

Update the component mapping to focusIndex and try again

Comment: Hello ageoff, Thank you for the swift response, yes I changed the naming to the correct name but I'm still having the same issue.
I even attempted to change it to an object but the problem persisted. I wanted to ask if maybe i was re-assigning the attribute incorrectly? I've ran out of ideas 
I changed it back

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, even now I'm uncertain where I made my mistake as even when I fixed all my variable names I had the issue but I stashed, re-did my work, restarted emulators and cache and it works.